# How to prevent NumberFormatter to round decimal numbers?

Tags: php, numberformatter

I am trying to write a general purpose function for formatting decimal numbers that works with any number of decimals — honoring the original number of decimals and current locale (which can be set to any that the local enviroment supports).

This is what I have (in a test):

```php
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'en_US');

$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

$num = 1234.56789;

$this->assertEquals('1,234.56789', $formatter->format($num, \NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE));
```

... but it will fail:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :'1,234.56789'
Actual   :'1,234.568'
```

By adding this line:

```php
echo 'MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS: '. $formatter->getAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS) . PHP_EOL;
```

... I was able to determine that by default `NumberFormatter` rounds the number to 3 digits.

Setting a large number for `MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS` like so:

```php
$formatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 100);
```

... will get me what I want, but I am sure I am missing something.

Is there a less hacky way to do what I want?

Comment: It can probably be done by adding a pattern as a third argument in `new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);`. But the links to the documentation don't work properly. This is a bit of a mess.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I understand but it's not "scalable" — the package must provide a number formatting solution to any valid locale setting. So I would need to research and write patterns for each locale.

Comment: @shingo no, since I am not doing any operation with the number, just formatting.

Comment: Computers cannot accurately store 1234.56789, so limiting digits is always necessary whilst formatting a float number to string. “formatting" is an operation.

Comment: *"honoring the original number of decimals"* That notion is not well-defined for floating point numbers. `sprintf("%.15f", 1234.56789)` gives `1234.567890000000034`.